# A connection (discovered by me) between prime numbers and the Hermite Constant in 3D

Tags: prime-numbers, characteristic-functions

Let $P(n)$ be a **[characteristic function of prime numbers](https://oeis.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_of_prime_numbers)**, such that

$$
P(n)= \begin{cases}  1,    & \small \text{if } n \text{ is prime} \\  0, & \small \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}   
$$

For instance: $P(n) = \pi(n)-\pi(n-1)$, where $\pi(x)$ is **the prime-counting function**. Knowing all that, we can evaluate the following identity (conjeture?) discovered by me

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{(-1)^{P(i)}}{i^2}= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{(-1)^{\pi(i)-\pi(i-1)}}{i^2}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}
$$

and it seems to approach (converge to) **[the Hermite Constant in 3 dimensions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePacking.html)**. So, obviously the question is: can you prove that sum is true?

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty much $\sum_Ci^{-2}-\sum_Pi^{-2}$, where the first sum is over the composites and the second over the primes, so it's pretty much $\zeta(2)-2\sum_Pi^{-2}$. The sum on the primes is sometimes called "the prime zeta function". $\pi/(3\sqrt2)$ seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: Indeed, little is known about that prime zeta thing.
Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared

Comment: [what we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) is $\sum_{p^k} \frac{1}{k p^{2k}} = \ln \zeta(2) = \ln \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but the value of $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^{2}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \ln \zeta(2k)$ is unknown

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Gerry Myerson's comment; $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ and the first $104$ digits of $P(2)=\sum_{p}p^{-2}$ can be found at:  http://oeis.org/A085548. We now see that $$\zeta(2)-2P(2)=0.7404392267660955...$$, while 
$$\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}=0.7404804896930609...$$
So no, you can't prove it because, sadly, it's false.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(n)$ be a **[characteristic function of prime numbers](https://oeis.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_of_prime_numbers)**. Then, it's easy to see that:
$$
(-1)^{\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(i)}= 1- 2 \chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(i)
$$
therefore,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{(-1)^{\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(i)}}{i^2}= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{1- 2 \chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(i)}{i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{1}{i^2}- 2 \sum_{i=1}^\infty \cfrac{\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(i)}{i^2} = \\ \\ =\zeta(2)-2 \sum_p \cfrac{1}{p^2} = \zeta(2)-2 P(2)= \\ \\ \\ = 0.7404392267660954394593\ldots
$$
where P(2) means [Prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) of 2. The conclusion is that

$$
\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}\neq \zeta(2)-2 P(2)
$$
because
$$
\frac{\pi ^2 -\pi \sqrt{2}}{12}<P(2)
$$
so, I was wrong about my conjeture, but Gerry Myerson and Mastrem are right.

Regards

Comment: however, it was interesting